# C scan unicode character from string

Tags: c, string, scanf, widechar

I've wchar_t type string which includes unicode characters like "ş, ç, ü,.."
I need to take this character one by one from string but I can't read them with sscanf. I couldn't found alternative function. So what should I do?

Comment: `int swscanf(const wchar_t *buffer, const wchar_t *format [, argument ] ... );`

Comment: You can't just have a "unicode character", it has to be encoded in some way (UTF-8, UTF-16, etc). What is the encoding of the string?

Comment: en_US.utf-8 encoding

Comment: Then you simply can't use `scanf` (or `wscanf`) to read the characters, as it has no knowledge of the multi-byte encoding used for UTF-8. Use a library such as [libiconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) to handle it.

Comment: Thank you, I study on library you said, but I've fixed that problem like this:
Now it works. Thank you all!

#include <locale.h>
int main(void) {
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

Comment: @thoron While that makes some functions behave correctly, some others won´t, and things like element-wise char access in an array / std::string / whatever are guarenteed to break. Don´t use this as perfect solution except you want a great bug source.